# How to search for the word 'IN' in an XML CLOB using Oracle Full Text Search?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, full-text-search

I am trying to track down a bug in some existing code and I'm new to Oracle full text searches...

I'm having trouble with a query that returns rows that contain the word 'IN' from within an xml document.

For example, lets say I have this snippet stored in a CLOB in my Oracle 10 database:

```
<a>
  <b>IN</b>
</a>
```

I want to find all entries that have b with a value of 'IN' so I create a where clause that looks like this:

```
where contains(column, '(IN) INPATH (//b)') > 0;
```

But this returns no results. I have tried searching for other terms such as 'AA' and 'BS' and it works fine.

I have searched the Google and the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb09sea.htm#CBBDAEAJ) for reserved words but I don't see 'IN' listed there. Obviously, it is a reserved word in SQL but I don't see a reference to that in the full test search or XPATH docs.

I have also tried escaping the term by surrounding it with {}, "", and any crazy thing I could think of but that doesn't help.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is probably right. In full text search the term is 'stop word'. If you don't define your own stoplist then a default is used: `CTXSYS.DEFAULT_STOPLIST`. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/text.901/a90121/astopsu2.htm#43324) article for the default English stoplist. The word 'in' is in it.

You can either remove stop words or create your own stoplist using the [CTX_DDL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cddlpkg.htm) package, specifically `CTX_DDL.REMOVE_STOPWORD` or `CTX_DDL.CREATE_STOPLIST`.